# Spring generic types dependency injection failing with AOP enabled

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, aop, spring-aop

I've a Spring Boot application (1.5.9) where I implement two converters and an component making use of one of these

```
@Component
public class Converter1 implements Converter<A,B> {
  public B convert(A a) {
    ...
  }
}

@Component
public class Converter2 implements Converter<B,C> {
  public C convert(B b) {
    ...
  }
}

@Component
public class Converter1Consumer {

  private Converter<A,B> converter

  public Converter1Consumer(Converter<A,B> converter) {
    this.converter = converter;
  }
  ...
}
```

Everything works fine and is injected correctly until AOP is in use. Then I receive following exception:

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<?, ?>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: converter1,converter2
```

Everything works fine again, when I change the name from `converter` to `converter1`. I can understand latter as Spring matches parameter name to the bean name. Can somebody explain me the reason, AOP converting the parameter definition to `Converter<?,?>` in the `Converter1Consumer`?

Comment: tra this `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`

Comment: Would you mind also sharing your aspect code and Spring configuration? I have an idea what might be going wrong, but I do not like to speculate.